# EF Core and Postgresql generation expression is not immutable on modified_at column

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm learning aspnet.core

In laravel we can do `$table->timestamps()` to generate `created_at` and `modified_at` to be updated automatically.

After searching, I found out that we can do this in EFCore (i'm using postgresql with [npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html)

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(u => u.created_at)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(u => u.modified_at)
                .HasComputedColumnSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                .ValueGeneratedOnUpdate();
```

However I'm getting error:

> Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> ALTER TABLE "Users" ADD modified_at timestamp without time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) STORED;
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P17: generation expression is not immutable
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)

I suspect the `HasComputedColumnSql` has couple of problem but I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You have to resort to a trigger for this. As the error indicates *generated always* must be immutable which Current_Timestamp is not (it's defined as stable). Moreover it would not work as the column name seems to suggest. The column name suggests it should be updated every time the row itself is updated but a generated "stored" column not based on another column in the row could never be updated from the value generated on the insert.  Define the column with default current_timestamp (just like create_at) then an update trigger and new.updated_at = current_timestamp;

Comment: Instead of creating trigger straight in postgres. How do I do that in ef core? Also I can't seem to find that in their docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html, does this mean that even the default value in `created_at` column is  mutable after?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to create a trigger through the  obfuscation layer (EF Core or any other ORM). As far a created_at  being mutable after the insert; in a word Yes.